# Count performances in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I am building a network of message posting. in an Asynchronous process, after a post has been uploaded, i have to query the database and make some counts on some documents.

For example, i have to know how many documents with id: 'document1' are in my collection 'collectionA', after each post is inserted. Considering it is an asynchronous process that is not directly involved with time application responds (so i don't need super speedy), is it sustainable to do many-many counts on many documents (for example querying a database and counts 3M of documents each time a post is inserted)? how much counting is a light calculation for mongoDB? is maybe better if i create index for those fields am i going to query? will this calculation light and sustainable in a scalable application? How much could these counts overload the system?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example? If you insert a document, couldn't you update a local cached count without doing a full count again on the DB?

Comment: no, cause documents automatically delete after a chertain time (TTL collection), and i always need the last updated value (how many are still in?) when i insert a new document. each last document becomes the last updated value, this is my cache. @WiredPrairie

Comment: If you don't index the field, it will need to do a full collection scan every time.

Comment: The problem with this question is that you are not showing us what you are **actually** doing, and what a "document" **actually** looks like. Without that, this is not a question that can be answered. Please edit your question with **that** information included.

Comment: if i do index the field, will this scan be avoided also if documents are auto-deleting (TTL collection) after certain time? i mean, will this count corresponds to document i actually have in the database? @WiredPrairie

Comment: Yes, it should correlate. Make sure you understand how TTL indexes and cleanup are used though: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/